# Views showing capital letters in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

Hi I am working in a app.

In the layout I have used text as "Tamil" in that format(Firs letter capital others in small).
**The part of the layout :**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/music_menu_logged_out_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/music_menu_header_bar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/music_menu_profile_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/username" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/music_menu_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_login_sidebar_bar1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Login"

            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/music_menu_signup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_login_sidebar_bar1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:onClick="musicMenuSignUp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/music_menu_or"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:text="- or "
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/music_menu_facebook"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_login_sidebar_facebook"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:onClick="musicMenuFacebook"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/music_menu_google"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.15"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_login_sidebar_google_plus"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Google"
            android:onClick="musicMenuGoogle"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

We can see that the text="" attribute in the "Format". But the layout looks like below.

[image]

Couldn't guess what mistake I did or anything happened wrong.I didn't use any stuff dynamically(programmattically).
What are all the possibles to this ?

Comment: Don't use some custom font (like setting this font somewhere in code)? This could be the issue.

Comment: what is your targetBuild sdk, 22?

Comment: try adding this to textview : `android:textAllCaps="false"`

Comment: @KarthikeyanVe I don't know, i had that problem too. It happened because of sdk version in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to textview : `android:textAllCaps="false"`